# I want this type of bottomsheet with trigger button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A151A.png)

I have tried many of customized bottomsheet, but none of those are do this thing that i want. I'm new in react native, I don't know how to do this thing. Please tell me?

Comment: try this 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a [github repo](https://github.com/hyetigran/rate-finder/blob/main/components/ActionSheet.tsx) of a similar component I made. I used this [medium article](https://medium.com/@saqib_61970/create-custom-draggable-bottom-sheet-with-react-native-e0b2705959b0) for reference.

You will be using "react-native-gesture-handler" package and the Animated component from "react-native".

Answer (score 0):

use

**react-native-raw-bottom-sheet**

run

```
npm i react-native-raw-bottom-sheet --save
```

here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet